# Какая разница в алгоритмах работы GC, Copying и Compaction?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Понятно что оба алгоритма, призваны "сжать" используемые ячейки памяти так, что-бы они шли подряд.

Copying, копирует данные из памяти и помещает в пустые ячейки, и тут кажется все понятно.

Compaction, вроде тоже копирует? Тогда какая разница? Или есть еще варианты "сжатия"?